# The connection attempt failed. When trying to connect to Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: heroku-postgres, datagrip

I'm trying to connect via Datagrip, but I don't know why I cant, I copy and paste the credentials so I'm sure it's not that what's wrong. I have search and found to change advanced settings, such as ssl, sslmode, etc.

I'm running on windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Other tool does connect, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the issue is caused by not trusting Unknown CA. So, you need to configure driver to trust that certificates.

In case IDE throws

> [08006] SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
> path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

One needs:

1. Go to data source settings and in SSH/SSL tabe enable *Use SSL*.
2. In Advanced Tab find setting *sslfactory* and set value to `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`
3. Apply changes and restart IDE.

For more detailed description read help articles:

- [How to connect to Heroku  PostgreSQL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-connect-to-heroku-postgres.html)
- [Connecting to Heroku Postgres Via
  DataGrip](https://help.heroku.com/S6LGZBIE/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-via-datagrip)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34132974)

Comment: Also, linking to articles of your own employer without explicit disclosure may be classified as spam.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right. Changed.